# Unable to save differenent date format in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a form and have a date field.
I want to save different date format for date field instead django used.
I am getting "01-jan-2016" date and want to save as it is in my database.when i am trying to save this same format is raise an error

```
[u"'07-Dec-2016' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."].
```

**I know this type of question asked already but they do not solve my problem.**

**views.py**

```
post_date = request.POST['date']

lead_obj = CustomerLeads.objects.create(posting_date = post_date)
```

my models.py

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    posting_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: *save as it is in my database* if that is really what you mean, makes very little sense.  Each database stores dates in their own format, which no one cares about.  Each database also has utility functions to parse dates to/from string representations.  Django has extra stuff to make this portable across rdbms. Some good answers django-side already, check them. What you might care about instead is having your **db**, not django, configured to by default use dd-mon-yyyy format so that you see 07-Dec when querying it.  That is a different question, one that requires knowing your rdbms.

Comment: is this osrted out?

Comment: yes..it is sorted now by some different method

Comment: what is that different method you speak of?

Answer (score 2):

## [Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

## [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE)

> Date and time input is accepted in almost any reasonable format,
>   including ISO 8601, SQL-compatible, traditional POSTGRES, and others.
>   For some formats, ordering of day, month, and year in date input is
>   ambiguous and there is support for specifying the expected ordering of
>   these fields. Set the DateStyle parameter to MDY to select
>   month-day-year interpretation, DMY to select day-month-year
>   interpretation, or YMD to select year-month-day interpretation.

The table at the link shows that postgresql accept the format that you are looking for. But how is it stored? Let's try an insert

```
INSERT INTO stackoverflow_heatwatchlist(next_date_from, next_date_to) 
VALUES('1999 Jan 05','2001 Jun 06');
```

And when you select, what you get is '2001-06-06' and '1999-01-05'

## SQlite

Here you can insert in any format you want and it will be saved exactly as you entered, that's because sqlite does not enforce any strict type checking. Types in sqlite are purely cosmetic. but django has a different opinion on the matter and will not let you divert too much from the standard formats.

## [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)

A lot of flexibility in how the data is accepted for insert. Refer to the table at the link.  But how is it stored? '1999-01-05'

## In conclusion

How the date is stored in the table is totally irrelevent, all that matters is what formats are accepted for input and how it's displayed. And that's where django's and python's excellent date and time formats come into play.

If you are not happy with them, you have two choices. The first is to store dates and times as unix timestamps and do all the formatting yourself, all you need is a little math really - a fairly common practice.

The second is to use CharField for storing your data but this is not very usefull. Not only do you have to do all the formatting and input validation yourself, any calculation would involve a lot of string processing and casting.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `'%d-%b-%Y'` to [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) in your project settings.

Comment: i add this DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%b-%Y').but raises same error

Comment: @vikrantVerma `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%b-%Y']` Like this.

Comment: No this is not working.Am i suppose add anything extra except date_input_formats

Comment: Maybe you can do `python manage.py syncdb` and restart your app?

Comment: @vikrantVerma also check if USE_L10N is disabled.

Comment: I set use_lion = False, done makemigrations and migrate but raises same problem

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py try this:

```
from dateutil import parser

d = parser.parse("07-December-2016")
print d
d = d.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
print d
```

Output:

```
2016-12-07 00:00:00
07-Dec-2016
```

It will handle various formats.

Comment: i tried this.this saves `2016-12-01` in my database but i want this 01 -Dec-2016

Comment: @vikrantVerma I think you might need to change the date format in your database I guess.

Comment: SO HOW CAN I DO THIS

Comment: this can only change fromat of date but ho can i save this format (d) in my datbase.i am facing problem when i save data into my database.