# How do I format my DATE to be in DD-MM-YYYY and later than 01-01-1993?

Tags: sql-server, date

```
CREATE table orders (
custNum INT NOT NULL CHECK(custNum >= 0 AND custNum <= 999999),
prodNum INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES product(prodNum),
date DATE NOT NULL DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') CHECK(date >= '01-01-1993'),
qty INT CHECK(qty >= 0 AND qty <= 100000),
PRIMARY KEY (custNum, prodNum, date)
);
```

As you can see from my

```
date DATE NOT NULL DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') CHECK(date >= '01-01-1993'),
```

What I'm trying to do is to ensure that when I enter a record it checks the format to be `DD-MM-YYYY` and also later than the date `01-01-1993`. However, I find that all the date formatting works mostly on `SELECT` statements, which I do not want. I want my records in the date column to be in the exact format I specify. How do you do that exactly?

Thank you and I appreciate any help. I'm learning SQL and constraints. I'm a beginner so I hope to make this as simple as possible (preferable a solution to my one line statement) so that I can understand better.

EDIT: Hi, I'm actually planning on doing it on mySQL/MariaDB but there's a CHECK constraint bug(?) so I'm actually using Microsoft SQL Management Studio. I'd appreciate it if it can work on Microsoft SQL Management Studio.

Comment: sql server or mysql?

Comment: Hi, I'm actually planning on doing it on mySQL but there's a CHECK bug(?) that it doesn't work so I'm actually using Microsoft SQL Management Studio. I'd appreciate it if it can work on Microsoft SQL Management Studio.

Comment: you are using Management studio as a client right?

Comment: @e4c5 hi actually I'm learning SQL, i'm not too sure about technicality but I downloaded Microsoft SQL Mgmt Studio, created my own database, and now trying to create my own table above. I want to create this table and a few more and then insert my own data and then try to practice.. so i'm not sure what it is.. i'm terribly sorry.

Comment: well the first thing to do is to figure out what RDBMS you are actually connected to because this si not valid mysql

Comment: @e4c5 hi thanks for your help i'm pretty sure i'm connected to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. my database is there and I'm working all my queries in this DBMS.

Comment: you cant change format database saves dates internaly, you must perform date_format and checks in selects and inserts

Comment: why don't you start by googling. 'Microsoft SQL Server' and 'Mysql'

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41182557/267540(disregard the mention of django in that question. it's not relevent)

Answer (score 0):

You are touching two problems in your question. The first problem is the representation. To alter the way dates are shown in selections. To solve this, run

```
dbcc useroptions
```

to check your current settings. The solution to this first problem is

> Ø Change the OS settings.
>
> Ø Change the server setting to British English.
>
> Ø Now create a new user and use dbcc useroptions
>
> Ø Now you would be seeing the option have changed.

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server/).

The second problem is with the `check` constraint. If you correctly change the `dateformat`, it is possible that your current `check` constraint will work, however, I recommend you to make sure that the correct [dateformat](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date) is used. You would need something like

```
CHECK (REGISTRATION_DATE > TO_DATE('01-01-1993', 'dd-mm-yyyy'))
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863954/check-constraint-to-restrict-the-registration-date-to-dates-after-august-26-200).

To achieve this, you need to [modify the check constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191273.aspx):

> In the Object Explorer, right-click the table containing the check
>   constraint and select Design.
>
> On the Table Designer menu, click Check Constraints….
>
> In the Check Constraints dialog box, under Selected Check Constraint,
>   select the constraint you wish to edit.
>
> Complete an action

Comment: @Ken you are welcome. If this answer solves your problem, then you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries):

> As opposed to YYYY-MM-DD, YYYYMMDD will never break.  If you decide to use any other format for your date string literals, at least for DATETIME and SMALLDATETIME types, you are leaving yourself open to errors or incorrect data should a user have different session settings, or should the application be moved to servers with different settings.
>
> In SQL Server 2008, the new types are a little more insulated from user or machine settings; still, I use YYYYMMDD for consistency and to be safe.

I realize you aren't using `YYYY-MM-DD`, but the fact that `YYYYMMDD` will not break still applies.

Below is a reformat of your original `create table` statement with a `YYYYMMDD` value

```
create table orders (
    custnum int  not null 
  , prodnum int  not null
  , [date]  date not null 
  , qty     int  not null
  , constraint [pk_orders] primary key clustered (custnum, prodnum, date)
  , constraint [fk_orders_prodnum] foreign key (prodnum) 
      references product(prodnum)
  , constraint [chk_orders_custum_gte_0_lte_999999] 
      check (custnum >= 0 and custnum <= 999999)
  , constraint [chk_orders_date_gt_19930101] 
      check ([date]>'19930101')
  , constraint [chk_orders_qty_gt_0_lt_1000000] 
      check (qty >= 0 and qty <= 100000)
);
```

Further Reading:

- [`cast()` and `convert()` > Date and Time Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
- [`format()` - sql server 2012+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)